# Laravel Vue Pagination not fetching the second page

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am having this issue after I uploaded file to shared hosting server.Pages Link are created and send to backend correctly. it is not feteching the next page instead it feteches the first page in the resopnse. Is it something to do with the htaccess file

**component tag**

```
<pagination :data="posts" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
```

**Method to update the page**

```
       getResults(page = 1) {
                    axios.get('api/post?page=' + page)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.posts = response.data;
                        });
            },
```

**PHP File**

```
public function index()
{
    if (\Gate::allows('isAdmin')) {
        return Post::with('category')->latest()->paginate(10);
    }

}
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well, you are setting `page = 1`, does changing 1 to 2 change anything?

Comment: It changes to page =2 and fetches the current_page i.e 1

Comment: Show us the php file responsible for retuning the data.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using laravel default .htaccess?

Comment: I need to use php version 7.Hence modified the htaccess file

Comment: I'm not .htaccess specialist, but simply adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php` to the default laravel .htaccess wouldn't have been sufficient? I'm almost certain that your .htaccess doesn't keep the url parameters such "page"

Comment: Is it right thing to do RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT,L]

Answer (score 0):

As I'm almost completly certain that your **.htaccess** is the problem and that you need to change the PHP version in that file, I would suggest you to add the line to the default laravel .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Swith to PHP 7.2
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This does not remove the public/index.php access.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I have modified the htaccess to remove access thorugh url like public/?

Comment: Any way the issue is resolved by changing  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT,L]

Comment: If you have **public** in your url, then you didn't configured correctly your **Document Root** path. It must not point to something like `/var/www/my-laravel-website/` folder but `/var/www/my-laravel-website/public/` folder

Comment: I am using shared hosting. I dont no where to find the Document Root

Comment: When you add a domain name, can you specify the folder? That's what I'm talking about.